# Do bonuses of the same type to specific saving throws stack if they can be both applied to the same effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bonus-type

My question may look unclear, so here is my problem : I found two character traits, one gives a +2 trait bonus to saving throws against charm and compulsion effects, the other gives a +2 trait bonus to saving throws against mind-affecting effects.

Dominate person is both a mind-affecting effect and a compulsion effect. Do I get a total +4 or +2 trait bonus against this spell if I pick both these traits ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## A total trait bonus of +2

They don't stack because they are of the same type. They still both *apply* to Dominate Person, but you only get the largest because they don't stack together.